# How can I update part of the value of an observable without re-rendering my whole page?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to use the async pipe as much as possible because I hear that's best practice since it manages observable subscriptions for you.

A very simplified version of my app looks something like this:

```
export class OrderDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  order$: Observable<Order>;
  lineItems$: Observable<LineItem>;

  constructor(
    private orderService: OrderService,
    private lineItemService: LineItemService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.order$ = this.getOrders();
    this.lineItems$ = this.getLineItems();
  }

  private getOrders(): Observable<Order> {}
  private getLineItems: Observable<LineItem[]>;
}
```

And then the template looks something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="order$ | async; let order">
  Order#: {{order.ID}}

  Line Items
  <div *ngIf="lineItems$ | async; let lineItems">
    <div *ngFor="let li of lineItems">
        <app-lineitem-card [lineItem]="li"></app-lineitem-card>
    </div>
  </div>

  Order Summary:
  Total: {{order.Total}}
</div>
```

Obviously this is simplified but the point is that order is needed pretty much everywhere on the page so I'm using the async pipe on the outermost div. This works great on first page load but the situation i'm running into is I update part of the order which only actually affects a very small portion of the page, let's say order.Total. I know I can do the following to update the order:

```
this.order$ = this.getOrder()
```

but that causes all of my components to be re-initialized (because of the ngIf).What's the correct way to handle this scenario?

Comment: You might be defining a component that is too big. For example, it might be better to have `OrderDetailComponent` composed of an `OrderIDComponent` a `OrderLineItemsComponent` and an `OrderTotalComponent` which each respectively encapsulate what you have defined within your single `<div>`. The advantage this *could* offer is that any changes to an `Order` would only be published to the `Order*Component`s and nothing else.

Comment: I know my sample didn't really show it but actually order detail page is composed of various components. The problem is the dumb components are still in one large container component that makes the api calls and is in charge of resolving the data at the outermost level. I could have the smaller components make api calls but that sounds contradictory to a lot of the archictecture best practices (ssupposedly). Presentational vs container etc.

Comment: I think the misnomer with smart/dumb component architecture implementations is the notion that there can only be one smart container at the top of the tree. I personally don't believe or adhere to this and create smart/container components where needed. I would try to avoid nesting smart/container components, but on a page, there's no reason why the header, content, and footer could not be three stand-alone smart containers which is what my answer is suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Read this:

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html

*But this time, we explicitly told Angular that our component **only depends on its inputs and all of them are immutable**. Angular then assumes that the MovieComponent hasn't changed and will skip the check for that component.*

Explained with as few words as possible: the change detection strategy affects how angular decides when to rerender a component. When using **Default**, it will go over all properties to check for changes (and there will be other triggers as well). When using **OnPush**, change detection will only do an equality check on your input parameters to decide if it needs to rerender. So any changes in your data will only be reflected when the instances of your objects have changed.

You need to think about immutability, and consciously choose when to clone your objects to trigger updates. On complex pages that handle a lot of data, this can really make a big performance impact.

Using ngrx/store or ngxs can help follow this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of the API side of things, why not have a **nested** `Observable`:

```
class Order {
  idThatWillNeverChange: FooType;
  someChangingProperty$: Observable<SomeType>;
}
```

is not impossible to have. How exactly you keep your loaded `Order` 'alive' (receiving updates) is a different matter.